# How to connect to the PCB of an Alcatel Linkhub HH40

Tags: pcb, soldering, serial, hacking, router

I recently bought an Alcatel Linkhub HH40 4G router. Unfortunately, the web interface doesn't provide the functionality I was hoping for (e.g., automatically disabling the radio functionality over night). Therefore I opened up the case to check if I can connect via USB, serial interface, etc to the operating system- but I cannot find a connector to connect to.

I attached the photos of the PCB. Can anybody help where/how I can connect to the operating system of the router (soldering is not an issue, if required).

Thanks!

[image: lower side]
[image: upper side]

Comment: What is the purpose of the microUSB connector in the 2nd picture?

Comment: It's the power supply :)

Comment: Not used for data as well? There are no traces leading from the pins where D+ and D- would normally be connected?

Comment: tbh, I didn't try that. It would be amazing if the micro USB plug would be data as well. Just a quick question: Are you by any chance aware of cables that I can plug into a power outlet and the computer at the same time?

Comment: Thanks, just found one :) So when I connect it to my computer and I call lsusb or dmesg, I don't see any new USB device in the list (the device is powered on and working, though)

Comment: there appears to be an unpopulated connector on bottom right in the first picture

Comment: @jsotola Which is this in the second photo: https://imgur.com/6sXVSKB ?

Comment: @user1252280, i have no idea what you are asking

Comment: @jsotola: lol, sorry for the confusion. I tried to mark the "unpopulated connector" you mentioned in the first picture in the second one. However, would you mind somehow marking the "unpopulated connector" in the first or second picture and explain what I need to connect to or what to solder on? Thanks :)

Comment: @user1252280, that 6 pin connector could be used for anything ... best thing would be to scope each of the pins during powerup ... it appears to be a spot for an RJ25 connector ... like an RJ45, but with only 6 pins ... https://wayconn.com/wp-content/themes/way/datasheet/MJEA-660X1XXX_RJ25_6P6C_PCB_RA.pdf ...

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for your continuous help! As you obviously realized, I am a total noob in this field. Therefore I need to ask more and more dumb questions: If I solder an RJ45 connector to it, how can I later interface with it? A serial connection? I will also check with the multimeter each of the 6 pins on powerup for changes.